# jQuery contains: exactly equal with a length function

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a variable from some text:

```
var foo = $(this).text();
```

... then if this ***exact*** text is found I want to perform an operation:

```
if ($("table td:contains(" + foo + ")").length) {
   console.log('text found');
}
```

However, assigning variable foo as either:

**test text 1**

or

**test text 2**

...will fire the function in the same way because they both share 'test text'.

**I've found this solution elsewhere:**

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
});
```

Which will apparently match the exact text, however I'm unsure how to merge this with my existing if statement/ .length function?

**EDIT : Full demonstration of code and context (included **@CertainPerformance** answer - still having duplication issues):**

```js
$( "a.product-title" ).each(function() {
 const text = $(this).text();
 const spanExists = Array.prototype.some.call(
   $('table td'),
   td => $(td).text() === text
 );
 if (spanExists) {
   console.log('text found');
   var associatedPrice = $("table td:contains(" + text + ")").next('td').text();
    console.log(text);
    $(this).closest('.simple-product-tile')
      .find(".lbl-price")
      .replaceWith(associatedPrice);
 }
});
```

```css
table {background: red; color: white;}
.simple-product-tile {padding: 10px;}
.product-title {background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="simple-product-tile">
  <a class="product-title">unique</a>
  <span class="lbl-price">Loading...</span>
</div>
<div class="simple-product-tile">
  <a class="product-title">foo</a>
  <span class="lbl-price">Loading...</span>
</div>
<div class="simple-product-tile">
  <a class="product-title">foo 2</a>
  <span class="lbl-price">Loading...</span>
</div>
<br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>unique</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 2</td>
    <td>2.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nym689fe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `.length` of the resulting jQuery collection:

```
const len = $('table td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
}).length;
if (len > 0) {
  console.log('text found');
}
```

But it would probably be more appropriate to use something like `some`, which will return as soon as a match (if any) is found:

```js
const text = 'foo';
const spanExists = Array.prototype.some.call(
  $('table td'),
  td => $(td).text() === text
);
if (spanExists) {
  console.log('text found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Regarding your edit, the problem is that your `"table td:contains(" + text + ")"` selector is matching *more than one element*. For example, when `text` is `foo`, both the td in the second `tr` and the td in the third `tr` are getting matched, because both contain `foo`. Then, with [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), the text of *both* price-related `td`s is getting put into `associatedPrice`:

> Gets the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements

Because you not only need to check whether a `td` with the exact text exists, but you also want to identify which `td` it is, you can use `Array.prototype.find` instead of `Array.prototype.some` - `.find` will return the found element (if any), rather than just returning a boolean.

```js
$("a.product-title").each(function() {
  const text = $(this).text();
  const td = Array.prototype.find.call(
    $('table td'),
    td => $(td).text() === text
  );
  if (td) {
    var associatedPrice = $(td).next('td').text();
    $(this).closest('.simple-product-tile')
      .find(".lbl-price")
      .replaceWith(associatedPrice);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.simple-product-tile {
  padding: 10px;
}

.product-title {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="simple-product-tile">
  <a class="product-title">unique</a>
  <span class="lbl-price">Loading...</span>
</div>
<div class="simple-product-tile">
  <a class="product-title">foo</a>
  <span class="lbl-price">Loading...</span>
</div>
<div class="simple-product-tile">
  <a class="product-title">foo 2</a>
  <span class="lbl-price">Loading...</span>
</div>
<br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>unique</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 2</td>
    <td>2.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also strongly suggest using curly braces even for a single-statement `if` body, unless the OP didn't (they did).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your answer includes a string const value 'foo', while my original example uses $(this).text();. Should I just be using 'const text = $(this).text();'?

Comment: Ok, so I'm still getting the same issue as before. To demonstrate I really need to show more context however. This is my fault. I should have done this from the get-go: https://jsfiddle.net/nym689fe/ basically you can see 'foo' has two prices as it's title was found twice.

Comment: @Dan382 - To improve the question, use the "edit" link on the question. To provide an MCVE, please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) rather than off-site resources. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). That way, your question is self-contained.

Comment: @Dan382 See edit - you should `.find` instead if you need to identify the element, rather than just checking to see whether it exists.